# Bridging two tap interfaces

Tags: linux, linux-networking, bridge

I am a total noob, this is my first ever experiment with kernel networking. I am attempting to create a bridge between two `tap` interfaces, and try to send traffic through. It is more of an experiment than for any particular purpose.

```
$ brctl showstp br0
br0
bridge id      8000.46846e0c0ff9
designated root    8000.46846e0c0ff9
root port         0            path cost          0
max age          20.00         bridge max age        20.00
hello time        2.00         bridge hello time      2.00
forward delay        15.00         bridge forward delay      15.00
ageing time         300.00
hello timer           1.98         tcn timer          0.00
topology change timer     0.00         gc timer         115.04
flags          


tap1 (1)
port id        8001            state            forwarding
designated root    8000.46846e0c0ff9   path cost        100
designated bridge  8000.46846e0c0ff9   message age timer      0.00
designated port    8001            forward delay timer   10.34
designated cost       0            hold timer         0.98
flags          

tap2 (2)
port id        8002            state            forwarding
designated root    8000.46846e0c0ff9   path cost        100
designated bridge  8000.46846e0c0ff9   message age timer      0.00
designated port    8002            forward delay timer    0.00
designated cost       0            hold timer         0.98
flags
```

I have the bridge  `br0` created, with both `tap1` and `tap2` added. I have a program injecting ARP packets into `tap1` using `libpcap`. Wireshark correctly shows the packets entering `tap1`. However, no packet shows up at `tap2`. I tried adding the follwing rule  in ebtables:

`sudo ebtables -I INPUT --log --log-level debug`

No packets show up in the logs. I'll appreciate any inputs.

Comment: Duplicate: https://superuser.com/q/1291813/750903

Comment: It is indeed a duplicate. Wasn't sure where to post.